# Compare folder size & conditional

Tags: bash, shell

What i'm trying to do basically is to get the folder size and check if it's greater than X size to do some actions (move files externally)...but the conditionnal doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER_SIZE="5709119"  
CHECK=$(du -s /var/backups/ | cut -f1)

echo "Current folder size $CHECK"
echo "Current SIZE LIMIT $FOLDER_SIZE"

   if [[ $CHECK -gt $FOLDER_SIZE  ]]
then
echo "$CHECK BIGGER THAN $FOLDER_SIZE"
else
echo "$CHECK SMALLER THAN $FOLDER_SIZE"
fi
```

The problem here is: i'm always getting the size of $check is smaller than $folder_size which not true since the $CHECK folder is mucher bigger than 5GB.

I'm getting as well this error when i run the script:

> bk_script.sh: 35:bk_script.sh: [[: not found

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bk_script.sh: 35:bk_script.sh: [[: not found
```

How are you running your script? The error suggests you're doing something like `sh bk_script.sh` rather than `./bk_script.sh`. Always do the latter so it uses the declared shell `/bin/bash` rather than `/bin/sh`. Plain sh does not have a `[[` operator.

Comment: That's right yes, i was running the script that way "sh bk_script.sh" i thought it was the same as "./bk_script" but it isn't ? Because the error just disappeard and the script seems to be working now! Any idea on how can i run it with crontab ? Thank you

Comment: @Boten In crontab, use the full path to the script (e.g. `/home/boten/bin/bk_script.sh` or something like that). Do *not* use the `sh` command, since that overrides the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`). BTW, I also recommend using lowercase (or mixed-case) variable names, since there are many all-caps names with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those, it can have bad effects.